# GraphQL named Object literal typeDef

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql

I'm working through a personal project and I'm trying to figure out the best way to define an Object of Objects that looks like the following in GraphQL's type definitions.

```
{
    "2020-12-29": {
    open: true,
    hours: 2,
    appointments: {
        "09:00-am": {
            appointmentId: "5223a4ef-a3cf-4e2f-b761-3e06193e2e21",
            userName: "Shaun Cartwright Glover",
            email: "Maverick.Quitzon31@yahoo.com",
            phoneNumber: "1-401-519-4771",
            avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ffbel/128.jpg",
        },
    },
    totalAppointments: 1,
},
```

As you can see, the name of the Object literal for the top level schedule is the date and the same is being done for each individual appointment. I'm also using graphql prisma if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow along with your example, let's break down your Object literal into the entities that it represents. In high level details, you're looking at

- An entity representing an Appointment
- The User associated with said Appointment
- A list of Appointments, associated with a certain AppointmentTime
- A list of AppointmentTimes for a given Day
- A list of Days, in the form of a a Schedule

To me, this seems to closely (but not exactly) match the data in the example you have. Based on this, I've defined a schema below, with some intentional design decisions that deviate slightly from your proposal.

Let's define some types, and knit them together, starting with a `User` type:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  # Depending on your requirements, a user may not have to provide a phone number.
  phoneNumber: String
  # Depending on your requirements, a user may not have an Avatar.
  avatarUrl: String
}
```

```
type Appointment {
  id: ID!
  user: User!
}
```

```
type AppointmentTime {
  time: String!
  appointments: [Appointment!]!
}
```

```
type Day {
  # The Day ID could be the actual day itself, i.e. 2020-12-29
  id: ID!
  open: Boolean!
  hours: Int!
  appointmentTimes: AppointmentTime!
}
```

```
type Schedule {
 days: [Day!]!
}
```

this would allow you to write a query (assuming you have a `getSchedule` query -- or something to a similar effect) like this:

```
getSchedule {
  days {
    id
    open
    hours
    appointmentTimes {
      time
      appointments {
        id
        user {
          name
          email
          phoneNumber
          avatarUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  days: [
    {
      id: "2020-12-29",
      open: true,
      hours: 2,
      appointmentTimes: [
        {
          time: "09:00-am",
          appointments: [
            {
              id: "5223a4ef-a3cf-4e2f-b761-3e06193e2e21",
              user: {
                name: "John Smith",
                email: "john@smith.com",
                phoneNumber: "123...",
                avatarUrl: "...",
              }
            },
            ...
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Note that this will end up producing a slightly different output than the one you posted. Why?

Well, I made the following design choices, and I'd encourage you to investigate them, too:

1. A user should be a separate field. In your example, the user and the appointment information are both under the same key -- `09:00-am` -- here, we want to leverage GraphQL's type system to normalize the schema by defining a `User` type that we can attach to an appointment. Better for introspection, too.
2. Your `appointments` key points to another *object* as its value, not a list. Since you're returning a list of appointments at the end of the day, you should model this as a [GraphQL List](https://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Type-System.List)
3. Added an `AppointmentTime` type associated with a list of appointments. This allows you to potentially have multiple appointments at the same time. (future proof)
4. Each day has a list of `AppointmentTime` --- this is optimal, as you are now no longer dependent on the key (in your case, `09:00-am`) to define the data associated with each appointment time. (future proof)

If you really did want the object literal to match the graphql output *exactly*, you can inline some of the fields I chose to extract to other types, but really, you should be leveraging lists for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for all of that information, so it seems that ultimately I should go with arrays for my solution rather than maps with the data living in the key names. I figured that this would be the case in the end. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yup! Exactly @LTFoReal